# YouTube Data API - Creating a live broadcast - getting [liveStreamingNotEnabled] - But it is

Tags: c#, google-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I'm trying to create a live stream on YouTube programmatically but I'm getting an error.  I've created a service account (will be run in the background from a web server application).  When I try to execute the livebroadcast insert request, I'm getting the error "The user is not enabled for live streaming. [403]".

But here's the thing, the only "user" of the account is me and I AM enabled for live streaming.  I was assuming that this permission would be shared by the service account that is executing the api call.  If that's not the case, how do I enable live streaming for the service account user?

Here's my code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
String serviceAccountEmail = "XXX";

var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
   new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
   {
       Scopes = new[] { 
           YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube
       }
   }.FromCertificate(certificate));

// Create the service.
var service = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "My App",
});

LiveBroadcast broadcast = new LiveBroadcast();
LiveBroadcastSnippet snippet = new LiveBroadcastSnippet();

snippet.ScheduledStartTime = new DateTime(2015, 6, 1, 14, 25, 0);
snippet.ScheduledEndTime = new DateTime(2015, 6, 1, 15, 25, 0);
snippet.Title = "Test Event";
broadcast.Kind = "youtube#liveBroadcast";

broadcast.Snippet = snippet;

LiveBroadcastStatus status = new LiveBroadcastStatus();
status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted";

broadcast.Status = status;

LiveBroadcastsResource.InsertRequest request = service.LiveBroadcasts.Insert(broadcast, "snippet,status");

broadcast = request.Execute();
```

Comment: What are you trying to stream from? What do you mean by "programmatically"?

Comment: Prior to being able to stream, you need to create a livebroadcast.  I'd like to create the livebroadcast using code (as above).  This is for an event that will have literally hundreds of live streams, many of which will run concurrently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a service account with the YouTube API at this time.   I suggest you try using Oauth2 authenticate it once then use the refreshtoken you have gained from your authentication to use for all other calls.

Little code to get you started:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Authenticate to Google Using Oauth2
        /// Documentation https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clientId">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <param name="clientSecret">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <param name="userName">A string used to identify a user.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static YouTubeService AuthenticateOauth(string clientId, string clientSecret, string userName)
        {

            string[] scopes = new string[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube,  // view and manage your YouTube account
                                             YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl,
                                             YouTubeService.Scope.Youtubepartner,
                                             YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubepartnerChannelAudit,
                                             YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly,
                                             YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload}; 

            try
            {
                // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
                UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                                             , scopes
                                                                                             , userName
                                                                                             , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                             , new FileDataStore("Daimto.YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;

                YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(new YouTubeService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "YouTube Data API Sample",
                });
                return service;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                return null;

            }

        }
```

Code ripped from the [YouTube sample project](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/YouTube).

Issue request: [Issue 5370:  Youtube v3 Google Service Account Access](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5370)

Comment: Thanks!  Been banging my head against this for hours!